# VBA Select command is causing my Macro to crash

Tags: excel, vba

This macro was working for awhile and then suddenly stopped working.  whenever I attempt to run the macro now it immediately shuts excel down.  I commented out the entire macro and then ran it one line at a time until I found where it started crashing.  it's on this line:

```
Sub Run()
'
' Run Macro
'

'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Sheets("Index").Select
...

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?  i've read the .Select is bad but I don't have the coding skills to create a workaround.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a sheet called "Index" within your active workbook? To learn how to avoid select, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194)

Comment: yes there is.  i rerecorded the macro today.

Comment: Do you have any event macros? Like `Sheet Change or Activate`? Also, make sure there is no lagging spaces in sheet name. Will need to be exact match

Comment: No.  what you see is the complete text.  everything else is currently commented out.

Comment: Are you sure that you run the code from the workbook having the sheet in discussion? Try 'Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name` and maybe you will have a surprise...

Comment: Delete `...` before `End Sub`

Comment: sorry to be confusing.  the ... represents commented lines.

Comment: @FaneDuru - I did that, the workbook is correct.